# Can i Call Window.open from confirm dialog Box?

Tags: javascript

Can I call window.open from confirm dialog box using javascript?

My Requirement:
In case browser pop up blocker was enabled means ,i want to open pop up window using `window.open();` but it was not happening so that i have to show the confirmation message which is "Browser popup blocker was enabled, now pop up has been open". now i click 'OK', on that time i want to call window.open() function.

```
<html>
    <body onload="openPopup();">
        <head>
            onload Popup Window
        </head>
    </body>

    <script>
        function openPopup () {
            var href= 'http://google.com';
            popUp = window.open(href, "_blank");
            if (popUp === null || typeof popUp === 'undefined') {
                var ret = confirm("this alert is displayed by Blocker, Continue to Open ?");
                if(ret){
                    window.open(href,"_new");
                }
            } else {
                popUp.focus();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Is it possible or is there any other way to handle this scenario?

Comment: do you want to open window as soon as browser loads, it is possible to show prompt and load window and even load without showing alert, which one do you want?

Comment: I'm afraid that if the first `open()` was blocked by the browser, any other subsequent `open()` will be blocked too.

Comment: @Hawk i want wherever i call window.open() function (without click function) i should open popup window. which means wherever browser shows pop up blocker i have to open.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Yeah correct, but browser popup blocker shows only while pop up window open without user interaction (NO Click Event).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Pop-ups are generally only allowed following a user's click, and as you've already seen in your code `onload` usually won't allow it.

However, you could use your own UI, to create a custom confirmation box that the user can click on to open the pop-up. This will work, unless the browser's pop-up blocker is overzealous enough to block even click-to-open popups without prior confirmation within the browser itself.

Comment: Ok, if any other way to disable browser pop up blocker using javascript / Jquery. My requirement only , open pop up window while browser blocks.

Comment: The whole point of a popup blocker is that it blocks popups. If there were a way to disable it, that would completely defeat the purpose.

Comment: That is because sites have banners with "Click Here" sh*t, they just **can't** open popups without user interaction and this - like you said - is the main purpose of the blocker. Otherwise web navigation will be like hell.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Of course, people could just be *nice* to each other and provide a pleasant browsing experience on their sites. Sometimes I think there should be no pop-up blockers. If a site throws pop-ups at you, then you stop visiting it and it dies a slow, horrible death.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol Can u Give me any other alternate way ? or simple code means it would be great.

Comment: Yes. Don't use popups. There is no legitimate use for them.

Comment: Ok, using jquery is it is possible?

Comment: ... Yes. jQuery is a magical programming language developed by unicorns. It runs with JavaScript but somehow accomplishes feats that are ***impossible***.